# How to read multiple text files and using the data at once?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am writing a code regarding to Zipf Law distribution. My task is to input 10 text files in one folder and output a table which contains four rows:
1. Rank (1,2,3,4...etc.)(r)
2. Word which have highest frequencies to lowest frequency.
3. Exactly frequencies of the words(f)
4. (r*f)
But I encountered three questions :
1. How to input the data of 10 text files(under a folder) into python at one time ?
2. How to use the data I analyzed into the table to draw it?
3. Is it possible to draw a plot graph after the table? (Using matplotlib?How?)

I have tried to analyzed the data for only one text file. But I can't find a way to analyze the data of 10 text files at once. Besides, I have no idea how to use the analyzed data to draw a table in python.

```
import re
from operator import itemgetter

frequency = {}

open_file = open(r'C:\最后上机作业（12.12.2018）\english\e6.txt')

file_to_string = open_file.read()
words = re.findall(r'(\b[A-Za-z][a-z]{2,9}\b)',file_to_string)

for word in words:
    count = frequency.get(word,0)
    frequency[word] = count+1

for (key, value) in reversed(sorted(frequency.items(),key = itemgetter(1))):
    print(key,value)
```

The output is frequencies of each word. But I am finding a way to sum up all the data of 10 text files at once and use them to draw a table in python.
Here is the code I have tried to draw the table, but I am mess up with the entry of data:

```
plt.figure()
ax = plt.gca()
y = np.random.randn(9)

col_labels = ['r','word','frequency','r*f']
row_labels = ['1','2','3','4','5'] #I am trying to arrange the data from highest frequencies to lowest frequencies, not only top 5 but all.Is it possible the code can arrange by itself?
table_vals = [[sorted(frequency.items(),key = itemgetter(1))],[21,22,23],[28,29,30]] #How to enter data I analyzed in table value?
row_colors = ['red','gold','green']
my_table = plt.table(cellText=table_vals, colWidths=[0.1]*3,
                     rowLabels=row_labels, colLabels=col_labels,
                     rowColours=row_colors, colColours=row_colors,
                     loc='best')
plt.plot(y)

plt.show()
```

[This is how the table should look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/emdyw.png)

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a help forum. See [ask] in the [help] to learn how to ask a good question.

Comment: @EthanK I am sorry I asked a detailed question, but I am just trying to make the question clear, thanks for reminding.

Comment: You're welcome!

Answer (score 0):

The efficient way to count words is using collections library and Counter class of that library. See the following example code where it reads all the txt file from the same location and counts the words

```
# this code reads all the text files in the same location.
import glob, os
from collections import Counter
words =[]
for file in glob.glob("*.txt"):  # or you can use full path
    f = open(file,'r') 
    for line in f:
        for word in line.split():
           words.append(word)    
# Print all the words in all txt files
print(words)
print("\nCounts..............")
#Counts words with
word_counts = Counter()
for word in words:
    word_counts[word] += 1  
print(word_counts)
```

In case of full path:

```
for file in glob.glob("C:/Users/Admin/Desktop/text/*.txt"):
```

**Test files content:**
first text file:

```
first text file c
count
anything any word
```

second text file:

```
second file and 
with texts 
dskfhj dsj fkjs
```

Create several text files in a directory and write a python file there, run the python code and see if you get intended result and then modify your code accordingly.

**Result of above code:**

```
Counter({'file': 2, 'first': 1, 'text': 1, 'c': 1, 'count': 1, 'anything': 1, 'any': 1, 'word': 1, 'second': 1, 'and': 1, 'with': 1, 'texts': 1, 'dskfhj': 1, 'dsj': 1, 'fkjs': 1})
```

Reference link: [Counter](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter)

Finally its easy to put all these counter data in a table based on the output.

Comment: I am so thankful for your help. Just one question....I entered the code exactly like yours , I used full path and I add errors = 'ignore' after the sixth line.The output became just [], Counts.............. and Counter() these three items......Can I know what's wrong with my code? Or is it any problems with the text files?

Comment: I have edited my question. Please help me. Thank you!

Comment: DB table is good. But the code you teached me just now doesn't worked right now. I dont know what problem with it :(

Comment: it is working for the first time.It doesnt have error. After I enter full path then it just have 3 line which are blank output: [],Counts.........,Counter().

Comment: `for file in glob.glob("C:/Users/Admin/Desktop/text/*.txt"):` notice the path and slashes not `\`  but  `/`. And this full path working fine for me. open the directory copy the path and replace the slashes. In python the path with "\" will not work you need to put "/"

Comment: and let me post the code for the table. when i get chance.